# Probability a city will be flooded

Tags: probability

Can someone please check my work for this problem?

The floodwalls of a city have been designed for a river level that will be exceeded on average once every 50 years.

a) What is the probability that the city will be flooded once in 50 years?

${50 \choose 1}(0.02)(0.98)^{49} = 0.372$

b) What is the probability that the city will not be flooded in any of 10 years?

$(0.98)^{10} = 0.817$

c) What is the probability that the city will be flooded at most, 2 out of 10 years?

${50 \choose 0}(0.02)^0(0.98)^{50} = 0.364$

${50 \choose 1}(0.02)(0.98)^{49} = 0.372$

${50 \choose 2}(0.02)^2(0.98)^{48} = 0.171$

total = $0.906$

d) What is the probability of no flood in 50 years?

$(0.98)^{50} = 0.372$

Particularly unsure of part c. and the fact that I have the same answer for parts a. and d.

Comment: I get $(0.98)^{50}\approx0.364$.  Note that part a), when simplified, is $(0.98)^{49}$, so part d) is smaller by another factor of $0.98$.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the Poisson distribution, not the Binomial?

Comment: @BarryCipra my mistake on part d. I also get 0.364. I was unsure about c because it is asking at most 2 out of 10 years. Not sure if this meant out of the first 10 years, any 10 year period? Either way, my method  I think is wrong because I am considering the whole 50 year period.

Comment: @DavidQuinn my reasoning for choosing the Binomial is that there are only 2 options, yes, there will be a flood and no, there will not be a flood.

Comment: But what's to say you don't have more than one flood in a given year?

Comment: @DavidQuinn not sure I am following. Part c. brings about the idea of there being the possibility of more than 1 flood. My thinking was I could calculate the individual probabilities of 0, 1, & 2 floods and sum together.

Comment: In using Binomial you are assuming that in any one calendar year it floods once or not at all. I don't think that"s what the question indicates.

Comment: @DavidQuinn My understanding was just the opposite based on the nature of a., b., and d.

Comment: I would say, certainly use Poisson distribution (see DavidQuinn).

Comment: In (c) you're computing "at most 2 out of 50 years", not "at most 2 out of 10 years".

Comment: @georg do you mean for all 4 parts or just part c.?

Comment: @HenningMakholm to correct part c, would this be a matter of changing the exponents 50, 49 and 48 to 10, 9, and 8, respectively?

Comment: @David: Floodings are certainly not uniformly distributed over a year -- there will usually be wild seasonal variations in flood risks. More problematically, the flood risk from day to day are _not independent_. If the river is high today, it will probably also be high tomorrow. So it doesn't seem warranted to use a Poisson distribution. The risk of two _different_ floodings in the same year ought to be much lower than the $\sim1/50^2$ the Poisson distribution would claim, because once the city floods _and we wait for the waters to recede_, that year's highwater season is likely over.

Comment: @samp1920: Yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: I mean for all 4 parts.

Comment: @HenningMakholm to be honest I think the question is a bit vague. In all likelihood, floodings are not entirely independent and random. The best the OP can do is count the calendar years as "flood years" or " not flood years" and use Binomial with $p=\frac{1}{50}$ in which case the approach is correct

Comment: Thanks everyone for input. I can now understand and appreciate why Poisson was suggested for this problem. Given lack of any other explanation provided by the problem, I believe I will keep with the approach of counting calendar years as "flood" and "not flood". I will try the Poisson approach for fun as well, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say

$\displaystyle P(X=n)_t=\frac{(0.02t)^n}{n!}\cdot e^{-0.02t},\quad$ t - count of years, n - count of flooding

a) $\displaystyle P(X=1)_{50}=\frac{1^1}{1!}\cdot e^{-1}\doteq0.368$

b) $\displaystyle P(X=0)_{10}=\frac{0.2^{0}}{0!}\cdot e^{-0.2}\doteq0.819$

c) $\displaystyle P(X\le2)_{10}=\sum_{n=0}^2\frac{0.2^{n}}{n!}\cdot e^{-0.2}\doteq0.999$

d) $\displaystyle P(X=0)_{50}=\frac{1^0}{0!}\cdot e^{-1}\doteq0.368$